# HEAD request leads to file name too long

Tags: redirect, http-headers, http-status-code-403

I have a website which frequently posts data from client to server of about 3200 characters. I notice that some users of the site when visiting one page in particular will make a HEAD request with the longest of the posted values preceded by a `/`. This leads to a file name too long error and 403 response code.

Is there some reason why browsers would frequently make these erroneous HEAD requests? is there a way for me to redirect those requests to the appropriate POST request?

Comment: What is the user-agent in the request?  In my experience HEAD requests come from monitoring software most often.

Comment: Here are two examples: `403 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:25.3) Gecko/20150425 Firefox/31.9 PaleMoon/25.3.2"` and `"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"`

Their browsing patterns are at least plausibly human, but you can never be too sure

Comment: Note that they have no referrer field present. Is that a common factor?

Comment: Is there any single-sign-on sort of environment in play with this site? They often have very long URLs (although I've not seen them with a HEAD).

Comment: You're correct - in all of the insatances that I've checked there was no referrer. I tried accessing the page myself by entering post data in the address bar and got through with no problem. 

Also - there's no sign in for the site.